# What is the difference?

Tags: arrays

Is there any difference in between these two declaration:

> (1). char ch;
>
> (2). char ch[2]

Actually the thing because of which this question arrived in my mind is the ending with '\0' i.e. null character so one of the 2 characters of the array ch[2] is null character hence only one character can be input in this.

Please help!!!

Comment: Hi, Ash and Welcome to COMPUTER SCIENCE STACK EXCHANGE take the tour of site and read some question and answers then you will have some more knowledge about the site.